# Android Proxy Setting

Tags: android, proxy, httpclient, http-proxy

I want to browse some website with proxy that i already have (with apps that i want to make of course). i want to change it programmatically (without go to settings or other 3rd apps included).

here is what i've done :

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {


 WebView web;
 String PROXY_IP = "MyProxy";  
 int PROXY_PORT = MyPort; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.web_view);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("MyURL");

        if (PROXY_IP != null) {                 
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().getCredentials(new AuthScope(PROXY_IP, PROXY_PORT));  
         new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username","passsword");
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(PROXY_IP, PROXY_PORT);             

        }
    }
```

I use webview for this. i already tried using phonegap and just editing the asset. but i'm confused about some php code. so i decided using webview instead.

The Problem is how to make my webview using my proxy.

Note: i'm using GB 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved. in webview `onCreate` i have to call url. like this `web = callURL();` and to load url use loadDatawithBaseUrl. after that you have to make a `public class callURL(){` . set the proxy in there. like this

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("your host", your proxy); //proxy that i need
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRouteParams.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
    httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(  
            new AuthScope("your host", your proxy),  
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(  
                    "your username", "your password"));
```

and then in httpget. call your url too. thats it. good luck

Comment: its not for webview. but its to get data

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Android Proxy Library ? 
https://github.com/shouldit/android-proxy-library

It's maybe a solution for you

Comment: the task is i just have to hardcode the proxy port and host. so i dont need the library.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method. I dont know this is whether correct or not. Just try.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,new
 NTCredentials(user, pass, null, null));
```

Comment: it says cast argument 2 to Credential. and here it is

`httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,(Credentials) new`.

Do i need to fill in username and password with hardcode too? or is it just when the url load, its asking for credential.  P.S : still wont load the webs

Comment: In this method you have to hardcode the username and password friend.

Comment: yeah i already tried that. but it seems i cant connect between web.loadurl and the set of myproxy.